# How to use Auto Text Typing Function multiple times? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, function

Good day, ya'll.

I have a quick question. Before I start, my knowledge of JavaScript ain't that great.

Below is a Auto Text Typing Function I'm using in JavaScript. To use it I need to add two classes, "type-js" and "text-js" to the element I want to animate. However I want to use it multiple times on different texts. Because when I add it to two elements it records the first ones text and uses it on the second text as well.

Here's the code:

```
function autoType(elementClass, typingSpeed){
  var thhis = $(elementClass);
  thhis.css({
    "position": "relative",
    "display": "inline-block"
  });
  thhis.prepend('<div class="cursor" style="right: initial; left:0;"></div>');
  thhis = thhis.find(".text-js");
  var text = thhis.text().trim().split('');
  var amntOfChars = text.length;
  var newString = "";
  thhis.text("|");
  setTimeout(function(){
    thhis.css("opacity",1);
    thhis.prev().removeAttr("style");
    thhis.text("");
    for(var i = 0; i < amntOfChars; i++){
      (function(i,char){
        setTimeout(function() {        
          newString += char;
          thhis.text(newString);
        },i*typingSpeed);
      })(i+1,text[i]);
    }
  },1500);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Now to start autoTyping just call the autoType function with the 
  // class of outer div
  // The second paramter is the speed between each letter is typed.   
  autoType(".type-js",200);
});
```

[Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0wHy.gif)

As you can see in the GIF above. I'm using the auto text typing function two times. In an element below and in the one shown in the GIF. But it records both texts to the variable. How can I make it reusable multiple times without it recording it to the variable and showing it on all elements? I want it to show individually. Like in the GIF above it supposed to only show, "Market Sector" and in a DIV far below that one, it should just show, "Company". Not both.

My apologies if this post sounds nonsensical. I tried my best to elaborate.

Thanks! And have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector returns multiple elements if there are more than one with the `type-js` class...
So run the code on `each()`.
See example.

```js
function autoType(elementClass, typingSpeed){
  // Run on each item that has the class.
  $(elementClass).each(function(){
    var thhis = $(this);
    thhis.css({
      "position": "relative",
      "display": "inline-block"
    });
    thhis.prepend('<div class="cursor" style="right: initial; left:0;"></div>');
    thhis = thhis.find(".text-js");
    var text = thhis.text().trim().split('');
    var amntOfChars = text.length;
    var newString = "";
    thhis.text("|");
    setTimeout(function(){
      thhis.css("opacity",1);
      thhis.prev().removeAttr("style");
      thhis.text("");
      for(var i = 0; i < amntOfChars; i++){
        (function(i,char){
          setTimeout(function() {        
            newString += char;
            thhis.text(newString);
          },i*typingSpeed);
        })(i+1,text[i]);
      }
    },1500);
  })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Now to start autoTyping just call the autoType function with the 
  // class of outer div
  // The second paramter is the speed between each letter is typed.   
  autoType(".type-js",200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="type-js">
  <div class="text-js">
  testing
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="type-js">
  <div class="text-js">
  testing again
  </div>
</div>
```